# How to setup access point that will work with newer devices (iPhone 5s, latest iPad, etc)

Tags: wireless-networking, arch-linux, hotspot, wireless-access-point, hostapd

Basically I've got an access point up and running and I can see the network on my the devices I've tested (iPhone 4S, 5S, new iMac and very old iMac), cannot connect to any device other than iPhone 4S. Even the 4S connected intermittently.

Here's my hostapd.conf file:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=smarrtEPOS
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=dedinha1415
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

And here's my dhcpd.conf file:

```
ddns-update-style none;
ignore client-updates;
authoritative;
option local-wpad code 252 = text;

subnet
10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
# --- default gateway
option routers
10 10.0.0.1;
# # --- Netmask
option subnet-mask
255.255.255.0;
# # --- Broadcast Address
option broadcast-address
10.0.0.255;
# # --- Domain name servers, tells the clients which DNS servers to use.
option domain-name-servers
10.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
option time-offset
0;
range 10.0.0.3 10.0.0.13;
default-lease-time 1209600;
max-lease-time 1814400;
}
```

I've got it kind of working through this [tutorial](http://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/comment-page-18/#comments):

Any ideas of what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that some newer devices need wpa=2 rather than wpa=3.  '3' should be both WPA and WPA2 but the probe response doesn't seem to contain the RSN IE when wpa=3.  So if the device doesn't like WPA then it won't connect.

Cheers,
Steven